# The identity component of an algebraic group is always parabolic

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, geometric-group-theory

> Essentially I was wondering if the quotient of an algebraic group $G$ by its identity component $G^0$ is necessarily always parabolic.

**My argument:**

This seems right since $G^0$ is a closed subgroup of $G$, therefore the quotient $G/G^0$ makes sense. Moreover its points are the fibers above $G^0$ hence is a finite quasi-projective variety. Thus it must be isomorphic (as a variety) to $\sqcup_{\text{finite}} \mathbb{A}^0$.

Note: The latter is complete?  Since, for any variety $X$, $\sqcup_{\text{finite}} \mathbb{A}^0 \times X \cong X$ (as varieties).

Comment: What is your definition of parabolic group?  I would call a *subgroup* $P$ parabolic if it contains a Borel, or equivalently if $G/P$ is a projective variety.

Comment: Also you're correct that $G/G^0$ is a finite group, but $G/G^0 \times X$ is a finite number of copies of $X$, it's not $X$.

Comment: By a parabolic subgroup P of G, I mean P is a closed subgroup and G/P is complete.

Comment: Hmmm...  Since $G/G^0 \cong \sqcup_{finite} \mathbb{A}^0 $, considering it as a discrete set of points in some $\mathbb{P}^n$, it is a (0-dimensional) projective variety; thus complete. Thus, $G^0$ would be parabolic..... 
or is $\mathbb{A}^0 \ncong \mathbb{P}^0$ and so I'm wrong?

Comment: Your last assertion on the product of a finite algebraic variety with $X$ is deadly wrong.

Comment: Yup.  I realise that now, but it is true a finite algebraic variety is projective, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the identity component $G^0$ is a parabolic by your definition.  Your argument is correct up until you say that $G/G^0 \times X \simeq X$.

Instead, to see that $G/G^0$ is complete observe that it is a finite group and so discrete as a topological space.  This means that the irreducible components of $G/G^0$ are points.  It's trivial that a point is complete and it's a good exercise to try and prove that a space is complete if and only if its irreducible components are complete.

Comment: Cool! thanks alot jim :)